# How many different possible outcomes are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A child is putting white clothes on two dolls. There are three shirts with different
shapes, and three pants with different shapes. The shirts and pants that one doll wore
should not be put on to the other doll. After putting clothes to two dolls, she colors
the shirts and pants with either gray or blue. The colors of the shirts and pants on
each doll should be different. How many different possible outcomes are possible?

My work: (3 shirt choices for doll 1) x (Two colors available for that shirt for doll 1)  x (3 pant choices for doll 1) x (Two colors available for the selected pants for doll 1) x (Two shirt choices available for doll 2)  x (Only one color available for that shirt for doll 2) x (Two pants choices available for doll 2) x  (Only one color available for the selected pants for doll 2)

so final result is 3 x 2 x 3 x 2 x 2 x 1 x 2 x 1 = 144 outcomes

But other answers I see give 72 outcomes

I am right? If not, Where have I gone wrong?
Also can someone show me how to do this with P(n,r) rather then with my logic?
Thank You

Comment: Are the dolls distinguishable?  For example, a male doll and a female doll?  Or are the dolls considered identical?  You might notice that $144 = 72\times 2$ which could explain the difference in counts

Comment: As far as "*with P(n,r) rather than with my logic*"... Don't bother...  You don't need to shoehorn formulas like that into problems like these.  Rule of product (*aka multiplication principle*) like you had used is far more fundamental and important of a tool to be comfortable with and is after all what is used to derive the formulas for P(n,r) in the first place.  If you *absolutely insist*, then you could phrase this using $P(3,2)$'s and $P(2,2)$'s in the obvious way... but this *increases* the total number of symbols used, so I wouldn't consider replacing like this useful.

Comment: The dolls are not distinguishable. I.E. they are both male dolls and female dolls. I've been told that one way to do this is P(3,2) x P(3,2) x P(2,2) but it doesn't make sense to me. When i make a tree diagram I get 144. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Again... if they *are not distinguishable* then you are doing something wrong by thinking of a "*first doll*" and "*second doll*" since you can't unambiguously decide which was the "first" versus the "second."  As such, you double-counted.  You can get around this a number of ways... the simplest is by pretending they *were* distinguishable and recognizing that you doubled the count as a result of doing so and fixing that by dividing by two.  If that is unsatisfying, then pick the shapes for the shirts simultaneously and distinguish them afterwards based on whose shirt was "smaller."

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. I definitely just double counted. Thanks for your help!